# For my situation, what accounting package would fit with CiviCRM?

Tags: accounting

I have civiCRM 4.6 installed on Drupal 7, and I'm looking how this fits together with any reasonably well known accounting package for either international or USA accounting systems.
In the latest version of CiviCRM there are some features that support the linking to financial accounts. 
What accounting packages currently have integration with CiviCRM? Either commercial or open source.
Thanks

Comment: If you could reword this question to either be more neutral ("what accounting packages does civi integrate with?") or specific ("here's my situation, which would work for me?") then we could reopen it.

Comment: I changed the title...and still not good? In that case I don't understand how to ask my question

Comment: Could you be more specific? You haven't said what kind of accounting you want to do, or what country you are in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We built some integration for Xero which is an online accounting system. The code isn't quite 'plug and play' but once set up it does the synch between contacts and transactions in both systems. Read more about Xero here https://www.xero.com/ and a blog about the integration here http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/civicrm-integration-xero